# Giving a nested route an alias in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, alias

If I want to provide an alias for a controller, I can use `map.resources :rants, :controller => 'blog_posts'` yoursite.com/rants points to the `blog_posts` controller fine.

How do I give an alias to a nested resource, for example yoursite.com/users/5/rants ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try:

```
 map.resources :rants, :controller => 'blog_posts'
 map.resources :users do |users|
   users.resources :rants, :controller => 'blog_posts'
 end
```

This will give you the `yoursite.com/users/5/rants/` url that you are looking for and it will generate the handy methods (for example: `users_rants_path(@user)`)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was driving me crazy.

Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you!